# SQL: multiple statements within a BEGIN and END

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to add a new column to an existing table which will be populated by a unique Guid value. I'm trying the following code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.columns 
        where Name = N'Product_GUID' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.Product'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Creating new GUID column in dbo.Product table'
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Product
    ADD Product_GUID uniqueidentifier  NULL

    UPDATE dbo.Product
    SET Product_Guid=NEWID()

    ALTER TABLE dbo.Product 
    ALTER COLUMN Product_Guid uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
END
```

This won't work becasue the second statement doesn't recognise the new column name. I can't put GO or ; at the end of each statement though, presumably because I'm in the middle of the BEGIN/END block.

What's the best way of solving this dilemma?

Comment: Aren't there `;` missing for t-sql?

Comment: Did you try it, or is intellisense just complaining? I have a feeling if you run it it will work, regardless of what intellisense says.

Comment: Yes if I try and execute this I get: "Invalid column name 'Product_Guid'."

Comment: I have the same problem and usually resolve it with a temporary Table (#). In comparison to table variables they are usable beyond a GO statement and even within dynamic SQL statements: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/

Comment: Actually my answer wouldn't run every time, if you look at it properly it only updates if the column is null and only alters the table if there has been an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement doing the update must be compiled after the column is added.

The way this is usually done is wrapping the statements in an `EXEC`:

```
EXEC(' UPDATE dbo.Product 
       SET Product_Guid = NEWID() 

      ALTER TABLE dbo.Product 
      ALTER COLUMN Product_Guid uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
')
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to set the default value and have the column be not null.  You'll get the same effect if you just set the default value to NEWID()

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.columns 
        where Name = N'Product_GUID' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.Product'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Creating new GUID column in dbo.Product table'
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Product
    ADD Product_GUID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID()
END
```

If you need to remove the constraint after, you can create the DEFAULT constraint after you define the column in the alter statement and then drop the named constraint right after.  If you don't name the constraint you'll have to get the name from sys.objects and then do dynamic sql to remove it.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.columns 
        where Name = N'Product_GUID' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.Product'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Creating new GUID column in dbo.Product table'

    ALTER TABLE dbo.Product
        ADD Product_GUID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT Default_Product_GUID DEFAULT NEWID() FOR Product_GUID;

    ALTER TABLE dbo.Product DROP CONSTRAINT Default_Product_GUID
END
```

Comment: I've done that for other tables but I can't do that for this particular table

Comment: Why can't you for this table?

Comment: Perhaps you just need to remove the default after the alter table is complete and the new values have been filled.

Comment: @shawnt00, I went ahead and added that in case that is what is was.  I wish the o.p. would've explain why though...

Comment: @Daniel Gimenez, I couldn't do it for this table as it's filled from a trigger and the main developer wants that process to throw an exception if the Guid isn't populated in the original table.

Answer (score 1):

You could just update the table afterwards and then alter it in another code block, a little something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select * from sys.columns 
        where Name = N'Product_GUID' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.Product'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Creating new GUID column in dbo.Product table'
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Product
    ADD Product_GUID uniqueidentifier  NULL
END
GO
UPDATE dbo.Product
SET Product_Guid=NEWID()
Where Product_Guid is null

if @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
Begin
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Product 
    ALTER COLUMN Product_Guid uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
End
```